# Writing a ReactJS component that branches rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `H1` component:

```
<H1 importance={importance}>foo</H1>
```

I want the rendering of `H1` to depend on the `importance` prop.

So I tried:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Default = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.2em;
`;

const High = styled.h1`
  font-size: 2.2em;
`;

function H1({ importance }) {
  return importance === 'HIGH' ? 
    (<High props={...props}/>) : 
      (<Default props={...props}/>);
}

export default H1;
```

But I get:

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have
>   returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Why is this?

Also I want the contents ("foo" here) to be rendered inside the child component. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I've checked on my project and it just works fine... you're error may be elsewhere...

---

> Also I want the contents ("foo" here) to be rendered inside the child component. How can I achieve this?

```js
function H1({ importance, children }) {

  return importance === 'HIGH' 
    ? (<High>{children}</High>) 
    : (<Default>{children}</Default>);
}
```

---

#### Update

If you want to pass all the props to the children, then you can use the `Object Spread Operator` on props: [Spread Attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)

```js
function H1(props) {

  return importance === 'HIGH' 
    ? (<High {...props} />) 
    : (<Default {...props} />)
  ;
}
```